# Putting stream cmd output to a textbox

Tags: powershell, cmd

I want to put continuous pinging done thru powershell cmd directly to `Text_Site`. 
I have `Text_Site`and a text box where you put the website, `PING` as a button and `Text_Status` as to where it should show the results. Heres my code:

```
[xml]$xaml = @'
<Window 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="TPM Script" Height="482" Width="479" Background="White">
    <Grid Height="375" Width="382">
        <Button Content="PING" Height="55" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,30,0,0" Name="PING" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140"/>
        <Label Content="Enter site name: " Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,45,0,0" Name="Label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133"/>
        <TextBox Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,74,0,0" Name="Text_Site" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="171" />
        <TextBox Height="114" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,241,0,0" Name="Text_Status" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="329" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
'@

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 

try
{
        $Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader. Some possible causes for this problem include: .NET Framework is missing PowerShell must be launched with PowerShell -sta, invalid XAML code was encountered."t
}
## CHECK FORM
    $xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{Set-Variable -Name "$($_.Name)" -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)} # find all names and make them accessible via a variable

#First Button 
$PING = $Form.FindName('PING')
$PING.Add_Click({
    <#Test-Connection -computername $Text_Site.text
       $text_status.text = "pinging"#>
$ping = Test-Connection -ComputerName $Text_Site.text -Quiet -Count 4
While($true){
    If($ping  -eq $true){
        $Text_Site.text = $Text_Site.text+"`n Ping Successful!"
    }else{
        $Text_Site.text = $Text_Site.text+"`n Ping Failed!"
    }     
}  

})

$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

Comment: What's the actual question? There's code and description about the desired outcome (good, too many questions lack these) but what, exactly, are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

Just tested your code, and it hangs / crashes fairly abbruptly when you try and use it. Well it did on my system and your results never appear in your 2nd test box.  I am going to assume that is your question. After several tries and force closing your form, a result eventually shows, but only in the site box.
So, there are some issues in your code outside of not getting the displayed results.

For example this...

```
If($ping  -eq $true){
    $Text_Site.text = $Text_Site.text+"`n Ping Successful!"
}else{
    $Text_Site.text = $Text_Site.text+"`n Ping Failed!"
}
```

Should really be this...

```
 If($ping  -eq $true){
    $Text_Status.text = $Text_Site.text+"`n Ping Successful!"
}else{
    $Text_Status.text = $Text_Site.text+"`n Ping Failed!"
}
```

Which is why the results end up in the site box and not the result box. Yet, that hard hang / which requires a hard close, is a real problem you need to figure out.

Yet, why go through the hassle of writing a form, unless it is a learning/homework thing or you are tasked with writing an app that need this.
Or you could do just as a call from a button from your GUI.

```
$SiteName = 'stackoverflow.com','stackexchange.com'
$SiteName | ForEach-Object {Test-Connection $_} | Out-GridView -PassThru
```

Of course you could put the above in a function for folks to use from your GUI.

However, if you need guidance on how to do what you are after. There are lots of examples of how to do this all over the web. Though these are using WinForms no XAML, mostly.

Here are just a few from the archives I keep around. I just hit the sites to make sure they were still there for you to download, review, or tweak for your needs.

PowerShell GUI Tool - Network Pinger - Version 2

```
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-GUI-Tool-f03b7523
```

This PowerShell script with GUI lets you ping an entire subnet or just a range. 
Run it by entering & '.\Ping Subnet form with gui.ps1' 
Enter the first three octets in the Subnet box 
Then enter the start and end range 
Adjust any variables and whether to show only pingable and host names, 
Press the Ping button.

```
https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/1464-ping-subnet-form-with-gui-ps1
```

Get computers ping status, IP, OS version, sp version, uptime and last boot gui

This powershell script with built-in GUI allows you to point to a text file list of computers and will then retrieve the following information for each computer in the list. Whether it is pingable Its IP address OS Version Service Pack Version Uptime Last boot time. Run it by en

```
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Display-computers-status-c8ff289d
```

Displaying Output in a GUI Application

```
https://www.sapien.com/blog/2014/12/15/display-output-in-a-gui-application-copy
```